# Getting a users location in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, geolocation, coordinates

I'm trying to get a set of coordinates back from the user so I can compare against another user.

Consider ebay, Autotrader, etc.

Once I have the coords it's not a problem:

```
var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(sLatitude, sLongitude);
var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(eLatitude, eLongitude);

return sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord);
```

I appreciate you can request to use the location of a device but I would like a solution that is not limited to mobile.

My question is, For a web app, how can I get the users location without paying to use an API?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you trying to get coordinates? Does the user have a GPS in the device using the application? If no GPS, how will you get coordinates? IP address lookup?

Comment: Since this is a web application, maybe use the geolocation API in the browser?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: "how will you get coordinates? IP address lookup? – user1934587390" Researching coords by ip address offered a solution but can also be 50miles+ out. I'm looking for a solution that is more accurate. 1 consideration was downloading a  list of postcode/coords but this seems like quite a big table and would be limited to the UK.